# Java weird behaviour on inserting date in database

Tags: java, sql, date

I am getting some weird behaviour when inserting a date into the database.

The database uses a `date` field and my input is in `String`, so I convert it to `java.util.Date` and subsequently insert it.

Converting code:

```
private Date convertToDate(String input) {
    try {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YY", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OutputProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

When `input = "19-9-2011"` it inserts `2010-12-26` into the database. Also when I had erroraneously set the locale to French it inserted `2011-01-03`, to make it doesn't make any sense at all.

And another followup question: My program will have to deal with dates in all possible formats, I can get the locale of the user who inserts the date most likely though. How would I go on doing that?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The year is represented by small caps `y`, not `Y`:

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
```

`Y` (large cap) is the week year.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending input String as `19-9-2011` format should be `dd-MM-yyyy` and 
pass 2 digits for the month `09` instead of `9`

Answer (score 0):

use java.sql.Date if you are interacting with the database dates.
Check your dateformat

Best option is to use timestamp instead of date. Store it as long (timeinmillis).